# if statements and stringWithFormat

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I need to know if there is a way to use if statements to display certain nsstrings, depending on whether or not that NSString contains any data.

I have an `nsstring`called `visitorInfo`.

The string uses data from other strings (i.e. which operating system the user is running) and displays that info. Here is an example of what I'm talking about:

```
NSString *visitorInfo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INFO\n\nVisitor Location\n%@\n\nVisitor Blood Type\n\%@", _visitor.location, _visitor.bloodType];
```

And it would display like this:

```
INFO

Location
Miami, FL

Blood Type
O positive
```

However, I have several pieces of data that only load if the user chooses to do so. i.e their email address.

This section of code below would do what I want, but my `visitorInfo` string contains tons of different strings, and if I use this code below, then it won't load any of them if the user chooses not to submit his blood type.

```
if ([self.visitor.bloodType length] > 0) {
    NSString *visitorInfo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INFO\n\nVisitor Location\n%@\n\nVisitor Blood Type\n\%@", _visitor.location, _visitor.bloodType];
}
```

So basically if their is data stored in bloodType then i went that code to run, but if there isn't any data I only want it to skip over bloodType, and finish displaying the rest of the data.

Let me know if you have any more questions

Additional details. I'm using an `NSString` for a specific reason, which is why I'm not using a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just build up the string as needed using `NSMutableString`:

```
NSMutableString *visitorInfo = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"INFO\n\nVisitor Location\n%@, _visitor.location];
if ([self.visitor.bloodType length] > 0) {
    [visitorInfo appendFormat:@"\n\nVisitor Blood Type\n\%@", _visitor.bloodType];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a string has any data in it by using the following

```
if([_visitor.location length]<1){

//This means there's no data and is a better way of checking, rather than isEqualToString:@"".

}else{

//there is some date here
}
```

**** EDIT - (just re-reading your question, sorry this answer is dependant on _visitor.location being a string in the first place)*****

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
    NSString *str = @"INFO";
    if (_visitor.location) {
        str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n\nVisitor Location\n%@",_visitor.location];
    }
    if (_visitor.bloodType) {
        str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n\nVisitor Blood Type\n\%@",_visitor.bloodType];
    }
```